# defineProperty is not defined

Tags: javascript

```
var vehicle = Object.create(null);
defineProperty(vehicle, 'transmission', "manual");

var car = Object.create(vehicle);
defineProperty(car, 'color', "red");
defineProperty(car, 'model', "subaru");

console.log(car.color);
console.log(car.model);
console.log(car.transmission);
```

Why the error **["ReferenceError: defineProperty is not defined"](http://jsbin.com/mivey/edit?js,console)**?

Comment: Because `defineProperty` is not defined. Where is it defined? If you want `Object.defineProperty`, then say `Object.defineProperty` (and read the docs before using it).

Comment: Just curious, why are you trying to use `Object.defineProperty` instead of just saying `car.color = "red";`?

Comment: Your question is not about "understanding prototypes". It's about `defineProperty`. You might want to consider editing the title to say something like "defineProperty is not defined".

Answer (score -1):

This is how you use defineProperty:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, descriptor)
```